# DateTime comparison in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to sort list of DateTime time elements in ascending order.I have realized normal operators like > or < don't cut it. What is the best way to compare two DateTime variables ?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Simply use the methods `isAfter()`, `isBefore()` or `isAtSameMomentAs()` from `DateTime`.

Other alternative, use `compareTo(DateTime other)`, as in the docs:

> Compares this DateTime object to [other],
> returning zero if the values are equal.

> Returns a negative value if this DateTime [isBefore] [other]. It returns 0
> if it [isAtSameMomentAs] [other], and returns a positive value otherwise
> (when this [isAfter] [other]).

Here a code example of sorting dates:

```dart
void main() {
  var list = [
    DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 3)),
    DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 2)),
    DateTime.now(),
    DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1))
  ];

  list.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
  print(list);
}
```

See it working [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d642fcff1687fd334aea18d9189930bd).

Comment: how can I compare 2 dates & time? Kindly share your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

**DateTime comparison in dart**

DateTime.compareTo(DateTime other):

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.parse("2021-12-23 11:47:00");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.parse("2018-02-27 10:09:00");

if(dt1.compareTo(dt2) == 0){
    print("Both date time are at same moment.");
}

if(dt1.compareTo(dt2) < 0){
    print("DT1 is before DT2");
}

if(dt1.compareTo(dt2) > 0){
    print("DT1 is after DT2");
}
```

DateTime.isAtSameMomentAs(DateTime other):

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.parse("2021-12-23 11:47:00");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.parse("2018-02-27 10:09:00");

if(dt1.isAtSameMomentAs(dt2)){
   print("Both DateTime are at same moment.");
}
```

DateTime.isAfter(DateTime other):

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.parse("2021-12-23 11:47:00");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.parse("2018-02-27 10:09:00");

if(dt1.isAfter(dt2)){
   print("DT1 is after DT2");
}
```

DateTime.isBefore(DateTime other):

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.parse("2021-12-23 11:47:00");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.parse("2018-02-27 10:09:00");

if(dt1.isBefore(dt2)){
   print("DT1 is before DT2");
}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is I how understood and implemented the code it will result in true / false in boolean mode.

```
DateTime valEnd = edate ;
DateTime date =DateTime.now();
bool valDate = date.isBefore(valEnd);
```