# How to compare current time with closing and opening time in flutter?

Tags: flutter, date, time

I want to compare the current time with start time (9:00) and end time(16:00). This start and end time are coming from API. I'm getting this error:

> Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1) 16:00

```
var formattedTime= DateFormat('kk:mm').format(currentTime);
int.parse(formattedTime) 
 <=int.parse(data['start'])||int.parse(formattedTime)>=int.parse(data['end'])
```

Comment: @sidra2006 No, it's about comparing dates while I just want to compare time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `compareTo(DateTime other)`, as in the docs:

> Compares this DateTime object to [other],
> returning zero if the values are equal.

> Returns a negative value if this DateTime [isBefore] [other]. It returns 0
> if it [isAtSameMomentAs] [other], and returns a positive value otherwise
> (when this [isAfter] [other]).

Here a code example of sorting dates:

```dart
void main() {
  var list = [
    DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 3)),
    DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 2)),
    DateTime.now(),
    DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1))
  ];

  list.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
  print(list);
}
```

See it working [here](http://dartpad.dartlang.org/d642fcff1687fd334aea18d9189930bd).

[*Originally posted by Julio Henrique Bitencourt*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56613951)

Comment: It still won't work for me because I only have time like 9:00 coming from API. If i compare this time with DateTime.now() I'll get error because there's no format like Date in api