# I get a expiry date and time from the api how compare it with the current time?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting a expiry time when i call the log in api in for format of **"Thu, 30 Dec 2021 10:24:34 GMT"** i want to get the current time and compare it.

Comment: just go through this weather you find smething https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65522526/how-to-compare-current-time-with-closing-and-opening-time-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

By using [DateFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class in intl package,
you can parse from string date to DateTime.
And by using 'isBefore' or 'isAfter' method, you can compare two DateTime.

[image]

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  String strDate = "Thu, 30 Dec 2021 10:24:34 GMT";
  DateFormat format =  DateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
  
  
  DateTime parsedDate = format.parse(strDate);
  print('parsedDate: $parsedDate');
  
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  print('now: $now');
  
  print('parsedDate is before now: ${parsedDate.isBefore(now)}');
  print('parsedDate is after now: ${parsedDate.isAfter(now)}');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this can help.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime then = DateTime.parse(expirlyDateFromApi.toDate().toString());
var difference = now.difference(expirlyDate);
```