# How to get the latest date time from the 2 dates | Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, flutter-web

I have 2 dates with time. I want to get the latest date from these 2 dates.
for example, 1st date and time is "2021-07-14 11:13:02" and 2nd is "2021-04-25 10:24:08". From these i want to find the latest date. How can i get this in Flutter and Dart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime comparison in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613875/datetime-comparison-in-dart)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate. Check out [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do by using DateTime.parse and isAfter(), isBefore() method.

[image]

```
void main()  {

  print(getLatestDate('2021-07-14 11:13:02', '2021-04-25 10:24:08'));
}

DateTime getLatestDate(String a, String b) {
  DateTime dateA = DateTime.parse(a);
  DateTime dateB = DateTime.parse(b);
  
  if (dateA.isBefore(dateB)) {
    return dateB; // If you want String, return b
  } else {
  return dateA; // If you want String, return a
  }
}
```