# Dart: Comparing two times from string

Tags: dart

Is there any way to compare two times in dart, suppose we have: 13:45 and 15:34, is there any way to find out that 15:34 is after 13:45.

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613875/datetime-comparison-in-dart) question, and there are functions to check isBefore or isAfter, but is it possible to parse time without having to parse year, month and day?

Comment: You could convert the times to `Duration` objects which can be compared with other `Duration` objects: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Duration/compareTo.html

Comment: Are you sure about the format? Are the hours always two digits? Is the separator always `:`? Is there never any whitespace around the digits?
If so, lexical comparison of the strings should work: `s1.compareTo(s2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert them to datetime and compare. ie:

```
void main() {
   var s1 = '13:45';
   var s2 = '15:34';
  
   var t1 = DateTime.parse('2000-01-01 ${s1}');
   var t2 = DateTime.parse('2000-01-01 ${s2}');
   print(t1.isBefore(t2));
}
```

EDIT: For a more direct, string sort like comparison (which I wouldn't suggest at all for Date\time values, unless you are 100% sure they are in sortable format) you could use compareTo(). ie:

```
print(s1.compareTo(s2) < 0);
```

Comment: At this point, my question looks like a duplicate, because I also thought of adding dummy year just for parsing it, but I was more looking for a direct comparison like strings in python.

Comment: @Sachihiro, if you want to compare them as strings (dangerous with date\time values in any language IMHO, unless you are sure they in ODBC canonical, ISO8601m or sortable format whatever you call), then you could use compareTo(). As far as I know Dart doesn't support >, <, >= ... operators for strings (don't know why) as in other languages. ie:  print(s1.compareTo(s2) < 0); would return true if s1 isBefore s2. Edited to add this.

Comment: Yes, I tested those methods out. I am just re-learning dart, haven't been programming in dart in a while a I need to see the options.